# Reading from memory and getting in char array.. What if a char in that contains 1 byte that suppose to be a 1 byte length and length is a number

Tags: c, byte

So I am reading memory that suppose to be bios info in C. And with usual read I get bunch of characters that.. The idea is those characters are making fields like Anchor "String" and 1 byte checksum and 1 Byte Length. But in C number is int or long. INT is 4 bytes. But I have char representing checksum and length is just taking 1 byte (1 character == 0x00 1 byte how to read it as int)

I am doing it like this . `unsigned char checksum=mem[0];` first 1 byte character represent checksum. But check sum suppose to be a number which should be `unsigned int checksum = mem[0]`.. The printing it prints 0

Then  moving on this is how I get 1 byte length from my char array `mem` at index 1.

```
length = mem[1];
//int x=mem[2];
```

And suppose If I have two byte number (Word length data) representing max size I am doing it like this at index 4 in my character array..

```
    char x1[3];
    memcpy(x1,&mem[4],2);
    x1[2]='\0';
    long v=strtol(x1,'\0',16);
```

Above is obviously printing wrong result for my max size. printing 0. And it does not seems all right either. long is 8 bytes But I have two byte that should represent my max size field in bios.

May be above is just wrong thinking that if I believe its correct or wrong. the fact is I really dont know how to handle this sort of conversion. Can any one please let me is above is wrong or correct. Or makes sense  for what I like to achieve

This is 2.1 table info from bios I am trying to extract. My anchor strings are printing correct but number fields not printing correct I am gett 0 for max size. 31 for length

https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_3.0.0.pdf

This is the code

```
void get_it(char *arr)
{

    char *mem = (unsigned char *) &arr[0];
    int length, i;
    unsigned char checksum=mem[0];
    printf("checksum %d\n",checksum);
    
    length = mem[1];
    int x=mem[2];
    int y=0;
    y=mem[3];
    
    
    
    printf("\nlength = %d version = %x\n minor version = %d",length,x,mem[3]);
    char x1[3];
    memcpy(x1,&mem[4],2);
    x1[2]='\0';
    long v=strtol(x1,'\0',16);
    
    printf("max size %lx\n",v);
    printf("entry point revision = %d\n",mem[6]);
    printf("~~ %c %c %c %c %c\n",mem[12],mem[13],mem[14],mem[15],mem[16]);  
    /*checksum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
       checksum += mem[i];
    }
    
    if(checksum == 0) break;
    
    mem += 16;
    */

    mem=mem+length;
    char type=*mem;
    printf("first type = %d",*mem);
    printf("length = %d",*(mem+1));
    
    int j=0;
    
    
    


}



int main()
{

    int fd=open("/dev/mychardev-0",O_RDWR);
    if(fd<=0)
    {   
        printf("fd %d\n",fd);
        exit(0);

    }

    size_t length=1048576;
    size_t x=0;
    char *buffer=malloc(sizeof(char )*length);
    while(x<length)
    {
        int valread=read(fd,buffer,length);
        printf("here\n");
        if(valread==0)
        {
            printf("zero bytes read\n");
            
            break;
        }
    
        if(valread<0)
        {
            printf("read return negative %d %d\n",valread,errno);

            break;
        }
        x=x+valread;
        
    }
    if(x>0)
    {
        size_t y=0;
        while(y<x)
        {

            if(*(buffer+y)=='_' && *(buffer+y+1)=='S' && *(buffer+y+2)=='M' && *(buffer+y+3)=='_')
            {
                                                
                
                printf("%c\n",buffer[y]);
                printf("%c\n",buffer[y+1]);
                printf("%c\n",buffer[y+2]);
                buffer=buffer+4;
                get_it(buffer);

            }
            y++;

        }
        printf("%x\n",buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ops no read\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But in C number is int or long.

`char` *is* an integral type which can be used to represent numbers, the same as `short`, `int` or `long`.

It has a maximum value of [`CHAR_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits).

One problem is that the signedness of `char` is [implementation-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2054939/2505965). When in doubt, be explicit with `signed char` (`SCHAR_MAX`) or `unsigned char` (`UCHAR_MAX`).

Alternatively, use [fixed width integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) to make it easier to reason about the byte width of the data you are working with.

The fields in the EPS table are denoted as being of size BYTE, WORD, and DWORD. These can be represented by `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, and `uint32_t` respectively, as you almost certainly want unsigned integers.

---

This code

```
char x1[3];
memcpy(x1,&mem[4],2);
x1[2]='\0';
long v=strtol(x1,'\0',16);

printf("max size %lx\n",v);
```

that attempts to parse the *Maximum Structure Size* as if it were a number represented by two characters is incorrect. The *Maximum Structure Size* is a 16-bit *integer*.

`mem=mem+length;` does not make much sense, as this would place you in memory beyond the table. I am not sure what the two `printf` calls that follow are trying to print.

Additionally, your example includes some errant code (unused variables: `i`, `y`, `j`).

Everything else is more-or-less correct, if messy.

---

Below is a simple example that seemingly works on my machine, using the `smbios_entry_point` table file. You should be able to use it as reference to adjust your program accordingly.

```sh
$ uname -rmo
5.14.21-210.current x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define EPS_SIZE 31
#define TARGET_FILE "/sys/firmware/dmi/tables/smbios_entry_point"

void print_buffer(uint8_t *eps) {
    printf("Anchor string: %c%c%c%c\n", eps[0], eps[1], eps[2], eps[3]);
    printf("Checksum: %02Xh\n", eps[4]);
    printf("Entry point length: %02Xh\n", eps[5]);
    printf("Major version: %02Xh\n", eps[6]);
    printf("Minor version: %02Xh\n", eps[7]);

    uint16_t mss;
    memcpy(&mss, eps + 8, sizeof mss);
    printf("Maximum structure size: %" PRIu16 " bytes\n", mss);

    printf("Entry point revision: %02Xh\n", eps[10]);
    printf("Formatted area: %02Xh %02Xh %02Xh %02Xh %02Xh\n",
            eps[11], eps[12], eps[13], eps[14], eps[15]);
    printf("Intermediate anchor string: %c%c%c%c%c\n",
            eps[16], eps[17], eps[18], eps[19], eps[20]);
    printf("Intermediate checksum: %02Xh\n", eps[21]);

    uint16_t stl;
    memcpy(&stl, eps + 22, sizeof stl);
    printf("Structure table length: %" PRIu16 " bytes \n", stl);

    uint32_t sta;
    memcpy(&sta, eps + 24, sizeof sta);
    printf("Structure table address: 0x%08x\n", sta);

    uint16_t nsmbs;
    memcpy(&nsmbs, eps + 28, sizeof nsmbs);
    printf("Number of SMBIOS structures: %" PRIu16 "\n", nsmbs);

    printf("SMBIOS BCD revision: %02Xh %02Xh\n",
            eps[30] >> 4, eps[30] & 0x0f);
}

int main(void) {
    uint8_t buf[EPS_SIZE];
    int fd = open(TARGET_FILE, O_RDONLY);

    read(fd, buf, sizeof buf);
    close(fd);

    print_buffer(buf);
}
```

`stdout:`

```
Anchor string: _SM_
Checksum: C2h
Entry point length: 1Fh
Major version: 02h
Minor version: 07h
Maximum structure size: 184 bytes
Entry point revision: 00h
Formatted area: 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h
Intermediate anchor string: _DMI_
Intermediate checksum: DCh
Structure table length: 2229 bytes
Structure table address: 0x000ed490
Number of SMBIOS structures: 54
SMBIOS BCD revision: 02h 07h
```

---

You may also be interested in [dmidecode](http://www.nongnu.org/dmidecode/) and its source code.

Comment: when I run your program on my module it says `Minor version: 05h` And I am getting anchor string correct also `Intermediate anchor string: _DMI_` correct. But why minor number in my program and in your program is reported as 5. But DMI decode prints 7. major number is 2 and `Structure table address: 0x00000000`..

Comment: Also I really like to ask where the devices and components struct starts. Is it right after reading SMBIOS entry point struct(entry point struct that u showed)

Comment: I'm not sure why your program disagrees with dmidecode on minor version (both 2.5 and 2.7 are valid version of SMBIOS, though). You may have incorrectly integrated what I've shown here, or otherwise have a broken table; *Structure Table Address* being `0x0` looks questionable, as this should be the address of your device entries in system memory ([`man 4 mem`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/mem.4.html)). You can also check for `/sys/firmware/dmi/tables/DMI`. Again, reading the [source code](https://github.com/mirror/dmidecode) of dmidecode will provide much insight on this topic.

Comment: can u tell if there is any source code in kernel repository that creates this file "/sys/firmware/dmi/tables/smbios_entry_point" is it char device

Comment: A [note](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-firmware-dmi-tables) and see [`man 5 sysfs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysfs.5.html). You are free to dig around in the [kernel firmware](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/firmware) source code (`dmi-*.c` files).

Comment: I also tested dmidecode with my kernel module and its still giving me correct result. I will look into the source code. But it looks like on my system its not listing all pcie devices plugged into pcie slots. Any idea which function I should look into more in dmidecode source

Comment: To follow the program flow start in [`dmidecode.c`](https://github.com/mirror/dmidecode/blob/024b0fb43ada238659c61f8d2e1f9ddeae603708/dmidecode.c): `main`(L5685) handles the initial parse and scan, checking multiple locations. Depending on options, and data availability, `main` calls one of `smbios_decode` (L5518), `smbios3_decode` (L5470), or `legacy_decode` (L5470). These call `dmi_table` (L5369), and in turn `dmi_table_decode` (L5218). Also see, [`util.c`](https://github.com/mirror/dmidecode/blob/024b0fb43ada238659c61f8d2e1f9ddeae603708/util.c): `read_file` (L98) and `chunk_mem` (L174).